# set max number of inflection points using geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, gam

I am creating very basic plots to visualize trends in a dataset.  I'm using the gam smoother with geom_smooth, but this is over-fitting the data at several sites.  For example, in the very first facet, the smoother over-fits the red data points.

Is there a way to adjust my code to set a max # of inflection points to focus on the overarching trends in the dataset (e.g., max. 2 or 3 inflection points).

```
ggplot() +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", 
               data = df,
               aes(x = year, y = morpho, group = interaction(year, group), col = group),
               shape = 1, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", se = TRUE, 
              formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs"),
              data = df,
              aes(x = year, y = morpho, group = group, col = group)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ site) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

[image]

**EDIT (2022-12-19): following some of the comments raised by @GavinSimpson, I've tried to make some visuals of how changing k changes the shape of geom_smooth curve.**

For these plots, I've tried to create an example dataset that has a rough quadratic section followed by a roughly linear section. Ideally, I want to find a k value that would capture the inflection point at the 'peak' of the quadratic section and the transition from quadratic to linear (x ~= 5 & 10).

```
library(ggpubr)
library(ggplot)

df <- data.frame(
  x1 = c(1:19),
  y1 = c(1.1, 4, 6.9, 8.5, 10, 7.2, 3.7, 2.2, 1, #quadratic
         0.4, 1.6, 2.5, 3.7, 4.6, 5.8, 6.7, 7.9, 8.8, 10)) #linear

pk <- ggplot(data = df,
             aes(y = y1, x = x1)) +
  geom_point(col = "red") +
  theme_bw()

# vary k from 2 to not specified
ggarrange(nrow = 3, ncol = 2,
          pk + geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 2)) + ggtitle("k=2"),
          pk + geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 3)) + ggtitle("k=3"),
          pk + geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 4)) + ggtitle("k=4"),
          pk + geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 5)) + ggtitle("k=5"),
          pk + geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 6)) + ggtitle("k=6"),
          pk + geom_smooth(method = "gam", formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs")) + ggtitle("k unconstrained"))
```

[image]

The first plot throws an error message:
Warning message:
In smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec(object, data, knots) :
basis dimension, k, increased to minimum possible
Indicating that R is increasing the k from 2 to 3.

Only when k = 5 do we start to see the smoother begin to capture the two main inflection points in the data (x ~= 5 & 10).  But what does k = 5 mean?  It also seems that it's added another slight inflection point around x ~= 16.

At k = 6, the SE is reduced and the line comes even closer to each data point, and it looks nearly identical to the figure when k is not specified at all, which might be ok in this situation, but for my dataset, when k isn't specified there is a lot of over-fitting when I really just want to see the most important inflection points.

So still no clear answer on how to specify inflection points.

Comment: You may have a look at the help pages of `mgcv::gam` and `mgcv::s` ... and please provide  a reproducible data example and simplify your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion from @tpetzoldt, I was able to identify how to set the max. number of inflection points in the gam formula.

```
ggplot() +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", 
               data = df,
               aes(x = year, y = morpho, group = interaction(year, group), col = group),
               shape = 1, alpha = 0.4) +
  geom_smooth(method = "gam", se = TRUE, 
              formula = y ~ s(x, bs = "cs", k = 2), #k = number of inflection points
              data = df,
              aes(x = year, y = morpho, group = group, col = group)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ site) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

Comment: `k` doesn't set the maximum number of inflextion points (it simply sets an upper limit on the allowed wiggliness) and setting `k=2` is not going to work as that will get you *only* a linear fit (I suspect you got a warning or it was hidden by ggplot) and `k` got reset to at least 3.

Comment: Odd. I definitely got some nonlinear lines with this and no warnings to make me thing folky was doing something different. If you want to write up an answer that shows how to set the number of inflection points and why, I will accept that.

Comment: @GavinSimpson is the correct term knots instead of k?

Comment: I trust you; my point is that `k` would be reset to the smallest allowed value for the basis (`k = 3`). Try, with your data:  `m <- gam(morpho ~ s(year, bs = "cs", k = 2), data = df)` and you'll see the warning. `k` isn't the number of inflection points of the resulting curve (but I note now that some people call knots, "inflection points", so you could call `k` that *in this instance*). But it still isn't 2 - it is 3 internal knots...

Comment: ...Then we have identifiability constraints; the basis contains the constant function which is confounded with the model intercept. Therefore, a sum-to-zero constraint it applied which removes the constant function and thence the maximum degrees of freedom of the spline when `k = 3` will be 2. In general, `k` is the *number of basis functions* - the default TPRS isn't really knot-based and `k` doesn't mean the number of knots in that case.

Comment: @GavinSimpson thanks for all your help with this!  my first attempt to model gams and I'm finding the terminology very confusing.  yes, I do get a warming message when I try to run m (Warning message:
In smooth.construct.cr.smooth.spec(object, data, knots) :
  basis dimension, k, increased to minimum possible), but unfortunately it doesn't say how many knots it has increased k to.
I decided to play around with ggplot a bit to see how it's interpreting the k parameter and I've update my question above with a few plots.  I'm still really unclear on how to set 'inflection points'.

Comment: (1/2) A couple of quick comments: (1) `mgcv` uses *penalized spline regression*, which is very powerful but makes the connection between 'number of knots/maximum complexity' and 'number of inflection points' much less transparent.  You might get somewhere with 'plain' splines, i.e. `geom_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ splines::ns(x, df=5))` (you can even pick the locations of the knots, if you think that will help: see `?splines::ns`). In principle you can control the number of inflection points by setting an appropriate prior on a *Gaussian process* ...

Comment: (2/2) Gaussian processes are available in `mgcv` (`s(x, bs = "gp")`) but it is not possible AFAIK to control the number of inflection points in the way suggested by Munch et al. 2017 [Munch, Stephan B., Valerie Poynor, and Juan Lopez Arriaza. “Circumventing Structural Uncertainty: A Bayesian Perspective on Nonlinear Forecasting for Ecology.” Ecological Complexity, Uncertainty in Ecology, 32 (December 1, 2017): 134–43. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ecocom.2016.08.006.]

Comment: @BenBolker thanks for that information on splines::ns and the reference!